Не могу написать необходимый вывод
Всем добрый день! У меня есть следующая функция:
def print_operation_table(operation, num_rows=9, num_columns=9):
    for i in range(1, num_rows + 1):
        for j in range(1, num_columns + 1):
            print(operation(i, j), end=" ")
        print()

Подскажите, пожалуйста, к этому же коду как добавить к функции чтоб она выводила: ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!., если строк меньше двух.
Я добавляю:
if num_rows < 2 : 
    print('ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!.')

Выдает такой ответ :
1 1 2 ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!.
А нужно чтобы только текст выводил!
P.S. "Совсем новенький в программировании!"

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

Если нужно делать проверку до цикла и не идти в него при num_rows < 2, то можно выйти из функции с помощью return:
def print_operation_table(operation, num_rows=9, num_columns=9):
    if num_rows < 2:
        return print('ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!')
    for i in range(1, num_rows + 1):
        cur_row = []
        for j in range(1, num_columns + 1):
            cur_row.append(operation(i, j))
        print(*cur_row)


Здравствуйте! Спасибо за помощь! еще одно условие есть - "Между элементами должен быть 1 пробел, в конце строки пробел не нужен." С пробелами все в порядке, разобрался. А вот как убрать пробел в конце строки не соображу пока. Может есть какие мысли у Вас по этому поводу?

Тут смотря как хотите оформить. Сейчас у Вас стоит end=" " - значит в конце вывода строки будет не перенос, а пробел. Выходит что все числа встают в одну строку, разделенные пробелами, но Вам не нужен самый последний после последнего числа?

В ответе написал вариант с созданием списка для текущего ряда и его распечаткой через *. Внутри ряда числа через пробел должны быть (если так возвращает operation), но в конце строк пробелов нет.

Здравствуйте! И снова огромное спасибо за помощь!!!)  все верно не нужен пробел после последнего числа, но и после  'ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!' - тоже пробел не нужен.   Как его  убрать?

Пробела быть не должно - если речь о переносе, то сделайте return print('ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!, end=''). Посмотрите про аргументы sep и end для print, чтобы самому полностью понять как и где можно настраивать вывод.

Вообще для такого специально в питоне есть инструкция assert, которая выкидывает исключение AssertionError, если проверяемое условие не выполняется:
def print_operation_table(operation, num_rows=9, num_columns=9):
    assert num_rows >= 2, 'ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!'
    for i in range(1, num_rows + 1):
        for j in range(1, num_columns + 1):
            print(operation(i, j), end=" ")
        print()

print_operation_table(None, 1, 1)

Вывод:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 8
      5             print(operation(i, j), end=" ")
      6         print()
----> 8 print_operation_table(None, 1, 1)

Cell In[4], line 2, in print_operation_table(operation, num_rows, num_columns)
      1 def print_operation_table(operation, num_rows=9, num_columns=9):
----> 2     assert num_rows >= 2, 'ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!'
      3     for i in range(1, num_rows + 1):
      4         for j in range(1, num_columns + 1):

AssertionError: ОШИБКА! Размерности таблицы должны быть больше 2!

Очень полезная штука, хотя вывода получается многовато, но он информативный - показывает и ваше сообщение и где именно проверка не прошла и какая именно.
